# How do I send a message on discord through a webhook using Discord py when a user sends a certain message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, webhooks

I am trying to create a basic bot that mimics the user that that message specifies.

I have not yet understood how I could go about getting user ids and then that user's nickname and profile picture. I made a demo for simply mimicking the user who invokes the bot's command but it leads to an infinite loop where the bot keeps repeating the message.

```
@client.event

async def on_ready():

    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content=='!test':
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('webhook url here', adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
        
        a=message.content
        webhook.send(content=a, username=message.author.display_name, 
                        avatar_url=message.author.avatar_url,wait=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, check if the message was sent by a webhook.

```py
async def on_message(message):
   if message.webhook_id:
       return
   # other stuff here
```

### References:

- [webhook_id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook%20send#discord.Message.webhook_id) Is an optional integer, normal messages will have `webhook_id` as None.